# How do I download the contents of a HTTPS web page?

Tags: c#, .net, https

To get to the page, I need a password. I have the password and I can get to the page.

The DownloadString(URL) function is downloading the contents of the LOG-IN page and not the actual page I want. Why?

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var credentials = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "username", Password = "password" };
                client.Credentials = credentials;

                string pageContents = client.DownloadString(url);

                if (pageContents.Contains("cheetah"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("yes!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No");
                }
            }
```

The above is getting the contents of the LOG-IN page as opposed to the page I really want. How do I get passed this?

Comment: If it's directing you to a login page, then that means the website is using forms/cookie based authentication.  You're sending HTTP basic authentication credentials, which is different, won't work ...

Comment: what do I have to get this to work? can you give me an example on how to use cookies?

Comment: I guess you could try a hack where you do an HTTP Post request that mimics what the login form is doing (assuming they don't use Capcha?).  Then you'd have to get the cookie you get back, and add it to a second request.  I'm not certain that approach would work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an un-authenticated client (`WebClient.DownloadString`) is asking for the page, it will normally be redirected to the login form where they can authenticate. Once credentials are passed and confirmed, the client will usually be brought back to the page they originally requested.

To get passed this, you need to simulate authentication, which typically involves passing a username and password, accepting a cookie, and using the cookie for further requests. At the very basic level, this should illustrate the approach:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace HttpsRequest
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var loginRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://your.url.net/login");
            loginRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            var response = loginRequest.Post("Login=foo&Password=bar");
            Debug.Assert(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

            var homeRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://your.url.net/home");
            homeRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            Debug.Assert(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
            homeRequest.GetResponse().Body();
        }

        internal static HttpWebResponse Post(this HttpWebRequest request, string data)
        {
            try
            {
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                var dataAsBytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);
                request.ContentLength = dataAsBytes.Length;
                var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(dataAsBytes, 0, dataAsBytes.Length);
                stream.Close();
                return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                return (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
            }
        }

        internal static string Body(this WebResponse response)
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make it work, you might want to have a look at an actual request sent to the site from a browser using Fiddler, FireBug, or a similar tool and then try and emulate as much of it as possible. For example, the site might require additional or different post fields, HTTP headers or have an invalid SSL certificate.